# receive data from callback functions in R

Tags: r, function, user-interface, callback, global-variables

I created a GUI to load data, and store the data for future use.

e.g.

```
loadData <- function(h,...){
  filePath <- file.choose()
  data <- someLoadDataFunction1(filePath)}
```

For now, I am using global variables to get data from the callback functions in GUI,instead of '<-'

```
assign('data',someLoadDataFunction1(filePath), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

But in future, I may need to load more data, which will cause more and more global variables.

In python, I met with the same problem, but there is another way except global data to solve the problem : build a class and save all the data into that class.

I wonder if there is something like that in R, by which I can store data in a separate file or environment, and future if I want to use them, I can easily read them from the file or environment>?

Or, for you experienced programmers, how do you usually get data from the callback functions in GUI.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no code here on which advice could be based. You can store variables in lists or environments.

Comment: @Roland it's updated, excuse me. But how can I assign to a list or environment ? And if assign to a list, that list will work globally? Thanks.

Comment: Well, instead of `envir = .GlobalEnv` you could use something like `e1 <- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv); assign("data", 1:10, envir = e1); e1$data`. You can then also decide if you want a hash table or not (see `help("new.env")`).

Comment: And of course you should use local variables where possible.

Comment: You could save the variables in a `.RData` file which you can load. It's capable of storing complex objects (e.g. S4).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes, I think so, and that's what Rstudio does every time I exit the program. But for .RData file, is this dynamic? that I can change the values each time?

Comment: You would have to re-write the RData file to disk, which may be prohibitively slow in some cases I would imagine.